# camera setParameters failed on LG G3

Tags: android, parameters, camera, lg

I'm setting parameters to Camera to prepare it for video recording in Android app.
This code snippet seems to work on multiple devices, but crashes on **LG G3**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1852)
```

Does anyone know if one of these parameters could be bad for that device ?

```
 p = myCamera.getParameters();
        surfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        p.setPictureSize(cam_width, cam_height);

        if (myCamera != null) {
            try {
                myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                List<String> focusModes = p.getSupportedFocusModes();   
                if (focusModes.contains(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
                    p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO); 
                p.setPreviewSize(cam_width, cam_height);
                int[] max = VideoQuality.determineMaximumSupportedFramerate(p);
                p.setPreviewFpsRange(max[0], max[1]);
                p.setRecordingHint(true);
                if(myCamera != null)
                myCamera.setParameters(p);
```

cam_width & cam_height are calculated in this way:

```
 camprev = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
 int high_width_preview = myCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0).width;
 int high_height_preview = myCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0).height;
 for(int i =0; i< myCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().size(); i++){
     Size sizet = myCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(i);
     Log.d("TAGME_NEXT", "supported preview sizeS: " + sizet.width + " " + sizet.height);
     if(sizet.width > high_width_preview) {
     high_width_preview = sizet.width;
     high_height_preview = sizet.height;
     }
 }

 cam_width = high_width_preview;
 cam_height = high_height_preview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved removing:

```
p.setPictureSize(cam_width, cam_height);
```